# Does not load scripts in node_modules folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, npm, node-modules

I have a asp.net mvc 5 project that utilizes npm for package management.

I include `node_modules` directory in output and publish my project.

I then upload my project on a plesk host.

The file(s) in the `Script` directory load successfully, however files that are in the `node_modules` directory do not load.

When I rename the `node_modules` directory to `Modules` it fixes the problem. However, this is not my answer.

Where is problem? plesk does not find `node_modules`?

Is there some permission policy in plesk that may be causing this issue?

Comment: How do you publish?

Comment: check this out 
https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/233

Comment: @trailmax use visual studio publish feature for create files and upload on my host

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to pack the node_modules? Is it not supposed to be installed by npm based on your package.json dependencies when your package is being installed or brought in as a dependency by other packages ¯_(ツ)_/¯

On a side note, even if you want to pack node_modules, is there an .npmignore or a .gitignore having a node_modules entry in it?